# Error receiving Ad when using AdMob SDK

Tags: android, admob

I have created a application with webview for displaying for AdMob. I am using the following code.

```
private AdView adView;  
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "/6253334/dfp_example_ad"); 
    View view = addHome(this,"https://www.google.co.in/");
    layout.addView(view,new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 100));
    final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();   
    adRequest.addTestDevice("1CD0A829B8C49C9F7590DD3B4C5EC553");
    adRequest.setTesting(true);
    setContentView(layout);
    new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();               
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);                
        };
    }.start();
}
```

I am always getting **onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred) error**, instead of getting the ads.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added your **INTERNET Permission** to your Manifest file and **made sure the device actually has Internet access**?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Are other applications on your phone able to access the Internet? What I mean is have you tested if other apps are able to access the internet? Maybe this is not an issue of your application, but of the phone in general being unable to access the internet for whatever reason.

Furthermore, what I see in your above code:

**You are calling "layout = findViewById(...)" before even calling "setContentView(...)".** This should actually result in a Nullpointer Exception when calling layout.addView().

**You could also try this code (inside your onCreate() method):**

```
   setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);

   AdView ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "yourid");

   LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);

   if (ll != null) {
      ll.addView(ad);
   }

   ad.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Comment: Yes, I have included Internet permission. I am running this application only.

Comment: What I mean is have you tested if other apps are able to access the internet? Maybe this is not an issue of your application, but of the phone in general being unable to access the internet for whatever reason.

Comment: In device browser, I am able to browse and able to download apps from play store. In this scenarios network down or network failure is not at all happened.

Comment: Sorry Phil. The code is there in MainActivity, miss that in the above code snippet.